# angularjs angular.min.js:85 Error: [$sce:insecurl]

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i have poor knowledge in angular pls some one help me in localhost its working fine..
and it was works well while php5 after upgrade php7 i got this error,

> angular.min.js:85 Error: [$sce:insecurl] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$sce/insecurl?
> p0=students%2Flistdata.php%3F
> at angular.min.js:6
> at getTrusted (angular.min.js:110)
> at Object.e. [as getTrustedResourceUrl] (angular.min.js:112)
> at angular-route.min.js:10
> at B (angular.min.js:94)
> at B (angular.min.js:94)
> at angular.min.js:95
> at h.$eval (angular.min.js:103)
> at h.$digest (angular.min.js:101)
> at h.$apply (angular.min.js:104)

**list page**

````
<?php
        global $title,$titleS,$CURRENTUNIT,$addNewFn;
        $path   = "../";
        include_once($path."includes/class.inc.php");
        $title  = "Students";
        $titleS = "Student Details";
        admin_userChk();
        error_reporting(0);
        if(!user_hasRights('menuStudentList')){ echo "<h1>403: Access Forbidden</h1>";exit; }
        
        
        
    
    ?>
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <section class="panel" ng-controller="listController" id="listController" ng-init="filter.SearchQry='';filterListData()">
                        <header class="panel-heading" >
                             List of <?=$title?>
                             <div class="pull-right">
                                
                                
                                <?php //if(user_hasRights('addNewProductinfo')){    ?>
                                    <a ng-click="addNewStudInfo()" class="btn btn-mini btn-success"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> Add New <?=$titleS?></a>
                                <?php //} ?>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="filterListData()" >
                                    
                                        
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" name="SearchQry" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="<?=$_REQUEST['SearchQry']?>" ng-model="filter.SearchQry">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <button class="btn btn-small btn-info" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        //$('#searchForm [name="InternalCompId"]').val('<?=$_REQUEST['InternalCompId']?>')
                                    </script>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-out m-t-small">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped b-t text-small">
                                <thead>
                                <tr align="center">
                                    <th >Sl.No</th>
                                    <th >Student Name</th>
                                    <!-- <th >Grade</th> -->
                                    <th >Parent Name</th>
                                    <!-- <th >Parent Occupation</th> -->
                                    <th >Contact No</th>
                                    <th >Email</th>
                                
                                    <th >Current Level</th>
                                    <th >D.O.B</th>
                                    <th >Joined On</th>
                                    <?php if(user_hasRights('editStudInfo')){   ?>
                                    <th >Edit</th>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php if(user_hasRights('deleteStudInfo')){ ?>
                                    <th >Delete</th>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
                                        <td>{{data.slno}}</td>
                                        <td>{{data.StudentName}}</td>
                                        <!-- <td>{{data.Grade}}</td> -->
                                        <td>{{data.ParentName}}</td>
                                        <!-- <td>{{data.ParentOccupation}}</td> -->
                                        <td>{{data.ContactNo}}</td>
                                        <td>{{data.Email}}</td>
                                        
                                        <td>{{data.CurrentLevel}}</td>
                                        <td>{{data.Dob}}</td>
                                        <td>{{data.Doj}}</td>
    
                                        <?php if(user_hasRights('editStudInfo')){   ?>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="editStudInfo($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info tooltipThis" uib-tooltip="Edit This <?=$titleS?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                                <input type="hidden" id="editId{{$index}}" value="{{data.StudId}}" />
                                            </td>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <?php if(user_hasRights('deleteStudInfo')){ ?>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="deleteStudInfo($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger tooltipThis" tooltip-placement="left" uib-tooltip="Delete This <?=$titleS?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <footer class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                    <ul class="pagination pagination-small m-t-none m-b-none">
                                        <li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="filterListData('First')" class="paginate_button">First</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="filterListData('Prev')" class="paginate_button">Prev</a></li>
                                        <li class="active">
                                            <input type="text" ng-model="filter.page" id="CurrentPage" class="form-control pull-left" style="width:50px" my-enter="filterListData('Current')">
                                            <a href="" onclick="return false"> of {{filter.totalPages}}</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="filterListData('Next')" class="paginate_button">Next</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="filterListData('Last')" class="paginate_button">Last</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <script>
                var pageConfig = {pageTitleS: "<?=$titleS?>", bcl0: "Home", bcl1: "<?=$title?>", bcl2: "<?=$titleS?>"};
                updatePageInfo(pageConfig);
                
                function listController($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.filterListData = function(gotoPage) {
                        $http.post(
                            'students/forms.php?render=json&gotoPage='+gotoPage,
                            $.param($scope.filter), {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} }
                        )
                        .then(function(response){
                            $scope.dataList         = response.data.list;
                            $scope.filter.page      = response.data.filter.page;
                            $scope.filter.totalPages= response.data.filter.totalPages;
                        });
                    };
                    
                    <?php if(user_hasRights('addNewStudInfo')){ ?>
                    $scope.addNewStudInfo = function() {
                        $http.get('students/forms.php?FormId=addNewStudInfo')
                        .then(function(response){   $('#myModal').html(response.data).modal();  });
                    };
                    <?php } ?>
                    
                    <?php if(user_hasRights('editStudInfo')){   ?>
                    $scope.editStudInfo = function(index) {
                        var editId = $("#editId"+index).val();
                        $http.get('students/forms.php?FormId=editStudInfo&editId='+editId)
                        .then(function(response){   $('#myModal').html(response.data).modal();  });
                    };
                    <?php } ?>
    
                    <?php if(user_hasRights('deleteStudInfo')){ ?>
                    $scope.deleteStudInfo = function(index) {
                        $.confirm({
                            message: '<b>Are you sure  that you want to delete this?</b>',
                            labelOk:"Delete",
                            onOk: function() {
                                //action
                                var editId = $("#editId"+index).val();
                            $http.get('students/forms.php?action=deleteStudInfo&delId='+editId)
                            .then(function(response){$scope.filterListData('Current');  });
                            }
                        });
                    };
                    <?php } ?>
    
                }
            </script> ``` 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    **index page**
    
      ```<?php
        $appPath = "app/#/";
        session_start();
        $path       = "../";
        include_once($path."includes/class.inc.php");
        admin_userChk();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="mainApp">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <base href="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/admin/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="A fully featured admin theme which can be used to build CRM, CMS, etc.">
        <meta name="author" content="Coderthemes">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/themes/start/images/favicon_1.ico">
        <title>WebPanel by Sura</title>
        <link href="assets/themes/start/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/themes/start/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/themes/start/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/themes/start/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/themes/start/css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/themes/start/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/themes/start/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="assets/themes/start/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
            <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries --><!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// --><!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../../https@oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="../../https@oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angular/page.css" media="all" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angular/animate.min.css" media="all" />
    
            <!-- Plugins   -->
            <link href="assets/plugins/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="assets/plugins/select2/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="assets/plugins/selectize/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="assets/plugins/selectize/selectize.bootstrap3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/theme/jquery-ui.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="assets/plugins/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href='assets/plugins/loading-bar/loading-bar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.min.css" media="all" />
            <!--   Plugins -->
      </head>
      <body class="fixed-left">
        <!-- Begin page -->
        <div id="wrapper">
          <!-- Top Bar Start -->
          <div class="topbar">
            <!-- LOGO -->
            <div class="topbar-left">
              <div class="text-center"><a href="./" class="logo"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Web Panel</span></a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button mobile view to collapse sidebar menu -->
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="">
                  <div class="pull-left"><button class="button-menu-mobile open-left"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button> <span class="clearfix"></span></div>
                 <!--  <form class="navbar-form pull-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Type here for search..."></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                  </form> -->
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
                    <!--<li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                      <a href="#" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><i class="md md-notifications"></i> <span class="badge badge-xs badge-danger">3</span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg">
                        <li class="text-center notifi-title">Notification</li>
                        <li class="list-group">
                          <!-- list item-- >
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="media">
                              <div class="pull-left"><em class="fa fa-user-plus fa-2x text-info"></em></div>
                              <div class="media-body clearfix">
                                <div class="media-heading">New user registered</div>
                                <!-- <p class="m-0"><small>You have 10 unread messages</small></p> -- >
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <!-- list item-- > 
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="media">
                              <div class="pull-left"><em class="fa fa-diamond fa-2x text-primary"></em></div>
                              <div class="media-body clearfix">
                                <div class="media-heading">New Order Placed</div>
                                <!-- <p class="m-0"><small>There are new settings available</small></p> -- >
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <!-- list item-- > 
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="media">
                              <div class="pull-left"><em class="fa fa-bell-o fa-2x text-danger"></em></div>
                              <div class="media-body clearfix">
                                <div class="media-heading">New Order Placed</div>
                                <p class="m-0"><small> <span class="text-primary">2</span> New Orders Placed</small></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <!-- last list item -- > <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"><small>See all notifications</small></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>-->
                   
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="./" class="dropdown-toggle profile" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Welcome <?=$_SESSION['adminName']?> <img src="files/<?=$_SESSION['adminPic']?>" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>settings/profile.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>settings/profile.php?action=ChangePassword"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Top Bar End --><!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->
          <div class="left side-menu">
            <div class="sidebar-inner slimscrollleft">
              <div class="user-details">
                <div class="pull-left"><img src="files/<?=$_SESSION['adminPic']?>" alt="" class="thumb-md img-circle"></div>
                <div class="user-info">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><?=$_SESSION['adminName']?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    
                                        <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>settings/profile.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile<div class="ripple-wrapper"></div></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>settings/profile.php?action=ChangePassword"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                                    
                      
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-muted m-0">IP: <?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--- Divider -->
              <div id="sidebar-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>home/home.php" class="waves-effect waves-light"><i class="md md-home"></i><span>Home</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>orders/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Orders</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>buyers/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa  fa-users"></i><span>Buyers</span></a></li>    
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>books/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-book"></i><span>Book Details</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>discount/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Discount Terms</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>coupon/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i><span>Coupon Codes</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>shopsettings/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Shop Settings</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>shipsettings/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Ship Settings</span></a></li>
                                <li class="divider"><br /><br /></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>levels/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i><span>Levels</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>students/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i><span>Students (Users)</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>webcontent/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i><span>Website contents</span></a></li>
                                <!-- <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>webnews/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>News & Events</span></a></li> -->
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>photos/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i><span>Photos</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>webvideos/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i><span>Videos</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>testimonials/listdata.php" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Left Sidebar End --><!-- ============================================================== --><!-- Start right Content here --><!-- ============================================================== -->
          <div class="content-page">
            <!-- Start content -->
            <div class="content">
              <div class="container">
                <!-- Page-Title -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h4 class="pull-left page-title pageTitleS"></h4>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb pull-right">
                      <li><a href="<?=$appPath?>" class="l0">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="l1"></a></li>
                      <li class="active l2"></li>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="page {{ pageClass }}" ng-view></div>
                            </div>
              </div>
              <!-- container -->
            </div>
            <!-- content -->
            <footer class="footer text-right">2015 © <a href="http://suratechnologies.in" target="_blank">Sura Technologies</a></footer>
          </div>
          <!-- ============================================================== --><!-- End Right content here -->
        </div>
        <!-- END wrapper -->
            
            <script>var resizefunc = [];</script>
            <!-- Main  -->
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/detect.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/fastclick.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/wow.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/themes/start/js/jquery.app.js"></script>
            
            <!-- Plugins   -->
            <script src="assets/plugins/select2/select2.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/plugins/selectize/selectize.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/plugins/summernote/summernote.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/plugins/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
            <!--   Plugins -->
            
            <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/plugins/validate.js"></script>
            <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
            <script src="angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="angular/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="angular/main.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/plugins/loading-bar/loading-bar.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    function getCustSummary(PartyId){
                        $('.modal-body').html('<img src="images/preloader.gif" alt="" />');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "customers/ajaxdata.php?action=getCustSummary&InternalCompType=&PartyId="+PartyId,
                            success: function (data) {  $('#myModal').html(data).modal();   }
                        });
                    }
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        
                    });
            </script>
            
        <div class="modal modal-light fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal modal-light fade" id="MainModal"></div>
      </body>
    </html> ```
  
angular confirm.js

    /*
     * angular-confirm
     * http://schlogen.github.io/angular-confirm/
     * Version: 1.1.0 - 2015-14-07
     * License: Apache
     */
    
    angular.module('angular-confirm', ['ui.bootstrap'])
        .controller('ConfirmModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'data', function($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
            $scope.data = angular.copy(data);
    
            $scope.ok = function() {
                $modalInstance.close();
            };
    
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
    
        }])
        .value('$confirmModalDefaults', {
            template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">{{data.title}}</h3></div>' +
                '<div class="modal-body">{{data.text}}</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">{{data.ok}}</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">{{data.cancel}}</button>' +
                '</div>',
            controller: 'ConfirmModalController',
            defaultLabels: {
                title: 'Confirm',
                ok: 'OK',
                cancel: 'Cancel'
            }
        })
    
    .factory('$confirm', ['$modal', '$confirmModalDefaults', function($modal, $confirmModalDefaults) {
            return function(data, settings) {
                settings = angular.extend($confirmModalDefaults, (settings || {}));
    
                data = angular.extend({}, settings.defaultLabels, data || {});
    
                if ('templateUrl' in settings && 'template' in settings) {
                    delete settings.template;
                }
    
                settings.resolve = {
                    data: function() {
                        return data;
                    }
                };
    
                return $modal.open(settings).result;
            };
        }])
        .directive('confirm', ['$confirm', function($confirm) {
            return {
                priority: 1,
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    confirmIf: "=",
                    ngClick: '&',
                    confirm: '@',
                    confirmSettings: "=",
                    confirmTitle: '@',
                    confirmOk: '@',
                    confirmCancel: '@'
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    
    
                    element.unbind("click").bind("click", function($event) {
    
                        $event.preventDefault();
    
                        if (angular.isUndefined(scope.confirmIf) || scope.confirmIf) {
    
                            var data = { text: scope.confirm };
                            if (scope.confirmTitle) {
                                data.title = scope.confirmTitle;
                            }
                            if (scope.confirmOk) {
                                data.ok = scope.confirmOk;
                            }
                            if (scope.confirmCancel) {
                                data.cancel = scope.confirmCancel;
                            }
                            $confirm(data, scope.confirmSettings || {}).then(scope.ngClick);
                        } else {
    
                            scope.$apply(scope.ngClick);
                        }
                    });
    
                }
            }
        }]);

main.js

    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angular-loading-bar']);
    
    
    mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/:name*', {
                templateUrl: function(urlattr) {
                    var queryString = "";
                    angular.forEach(urlattr, function(key, value) {
                        if (value != "name") {
                            queryString += "&" + value + "=" + urlattr[value];
                        }
                    });
                    //alert(queryString);
                    return '' + urlattr.name + '?' + queryString;
                },
                controller: 'mainController'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '' });
    });
    
    app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return function(url) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
        };
    }]);
    
    mainApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.sayHello = function(title) {
            alert(title);
            $scope.greeting = $scope.username;
        };
    
        $scope.greeting = $scope.username;
    }]);
    
    angular.module('mainApp')
        .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
            return function(text) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
            };
        }]);
    
    mainApp.directive('myEnter', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                if (event.which === 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                    });
    
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        };
    });
    mainApp.directive('prettyp', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $("[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ deeplinking: false, social_tools: false });
        }
    })
    
    function updatePageInfo(pageConfig) {
        $("title").html(pageConfig.pageTitleS);
        $(".pageTitleS").html(pageConfig.pageTitleS);
        $(".breadcrumb .l0").html(pageConfig.bcl0);
        $(".breadcrumb .l1").html(pageConfig.bcl1);
        $(".breadcrumb .l2").html(pageConfig.bcl2);
        $(".date").datepicker();
    }
````

Comment: The error message indicates that you are trying to access an insecure url. Try to access that url directly using a browser and see what the problem with that page ist.

Comment: i removed the url now the error shows this Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: This is a missing dependency injection. Check whether you have included all dependencies used inside the functions (`function($scope, $modalInstance, data)` ...). There is a  suspicious line here in `main.js`: `scope.$apply(function() {...` Where is `scope` injected?

Answer (score 0):

I changed http to https

Previous:

```
  base href="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/admin/"
```

Fixed:

```
  base href="https://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/admin/"
```

Comment: Both previous and fixed code are same

Comment: No bro i am new to stackoverflow its not accepting my answer mistakenly its happen but the answer is i changed the base url http to https then its worked